# Which verb is the best for sending/extending/offering condolences?

Tags: verbs

Which verb is the best for condolences: send, extend, offer? Or another?

Comment: to express condolences: I would like to express my condolences

Comment: Depends on context, I think. In a letter, text, email, etc. you "send" your condolences. If you're in person, for example at the funeral, you "express" or "offer" them. You might even inform the bereaved that they have already received your condolences: "You have my deepest condolences."